# Slide effect for drop menu with css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got a menu which I try to make responsive for smartphones.
I successfully did the drop down menu, but right now it doesn't have any effect and it just pop up when you press the bar icon.
I want to have the effect of slide down as you press on the bar icon.

pictures to explain better:

[image: before]
[image: after]

html and css:

```css
html {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background: #cecece;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  flex-grow: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo .bar {
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  flex-grow: 10;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: #8d8d8d;
  color: #ffff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .logo {
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgb(122, 122, 122);
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .logo .bar {
    display: block;
  }

  .logo .bar:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  nav ul {
    height: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  nav ul.active {
    height: auto;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css" />
    <!--
      FONT AWSOME=========================================================================
    -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h2>TestLogo</h2>
        <div class="bar"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('nav .logo .bar').click(function() {
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('active');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

appreciate any help!

Comment: you have to use specific `height` instead of `height:auto`

Answer (score 0):

set height value of *ul* modificator '*.active*' in pixels
css *transition* does not understand *auto* parameter

for deeper understanding of this problem read an article https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/ 
here is a quoute from it:

> auto values have been intentionally excluded from the CSS transitions
>   spec. It looks like it's been requested by a few people, but when you
>   think about it, it makes at least a little sense that it hasn't been
>   included. The browser process that re-calculates the sizes and
>   positions of all elements based on their content and the way they
>   interact with each other (known as "reflow") is expensive. If you were
>   to transition an element into a height of auto, the browser would have
>   to perform a reflow for every stage of that animation, to determine
>   how all the other elements should move. This couldn't be cached or
>   calculated in a simple way, since it doesn't know the starting and/or
>   ending values until the moment the transition happens. This would
>   significantly complicate the math that has to be done under the hood
>   and probably degrade performance in a way that might not be obvious to
>   the developer.

Anyway the best solution for your situation is manipulating *transform: scaleY* css property from 0 to 1 because this will do not trigger browser reflows

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.